# Unir Varios Resultados

Tags: sql, sql-server

Alguien sabe en tema de sql server, como unir un resultado que me de de 3 filas a una sola fila yo estoy utilizando este query pero no me los adjunta en un solo resultado, algo cuando hacer un reslutado XML pero con alguna función.

```
SELECT   ERROR + CAST(Campo1 AS nvarchar) + 'Pos' + CAST(campo2 AS nvarchar)+ 'Pro'+CAST(campo3 AS nvarchar) 
FROM Tabla T1 
INNER JOIN tabla2 ON campo1 = campo2 AND campo1 = campo2
```

Answer (score 1):

Podes usar la Funcion Concat

```
    SELECT CONCAT ( ERROR,  CAST(Campo1 AS nvarchar) , 'Pos', CAST(campo2 AS nvarchar), 'Pro',CAST(campo3 AS nvarchar) ) AS Result FROM Tabla T1 
INNER JOIN tabla2 ON campo1 = campo2 AND campo1 = campo2
```

Comment: Gracias por la pronta respuesta, en teoría el CONCAT es para unir varias cadenas del mismo registro, lo que ando buscando es unirlo pero de tres registros diferentes anexo los registros que quiero unir en uno      solo                   RESULTADO
                    707126372Pos1Pro1
                    707126400Pos2Pro1
                    707126523Pos2Pro2

Comment: Y como haría en el caso de querer mostrar resultados de 2 tablas, por ejemplo tengo "ingresos y egresos", ambas tablas tienen los mismos campos, con los mismos nombres y orden, comparten un campo llamado tabla la cual es "I o E" segun Ingresos y Egresos, necesito listar los resultados de ambas tablas pero que se muestre el campo tabla segun corresponda, intenté con UNION pero lo que hace es unirlos laterales, necesito que los resultados se unan por filas y no por columnas.

Answer (score 0):

La forma estándar en SQL es:

```
SELECT COALESCE(field1, '') || COALESCE(field2, '') || COALESCE(field3, '') FROM table1 ...
```

Comment: Gracias por la pronta respuesta, en teoría el COALESCE es para unir varias cadenas cuando se tienen valores null de pormedio, lo que ando buscando es unirlo pero de tres registros diferentes anexo los registros que quiero unir en uno      solo                   RESULTADO
                                                           Registro 1    707126372Pos1Pro1
                                                          Reigisto   2    707126400Pos2Pro1
                                                           Registro  3    707126523Pos2Pro2

Comment: Simplemente se hace el join, tal cual lo tienes, con los respectivos alias e igual te va a funcionar. Sería a.field1, b.field20, c.field 30....

Comment: Gracias por el post, me sirvió saludos..

Comment: Y como haría en el caso de querer mostrar resultados de 2 tablas, por ejemplo tengo "ingresos y egresos", ambas tablas tienen los mismos campos, con los mismos nombres y orden, comparten un campo llamado tabla la cual es "I o E" segun Ingresos y Egresos, necesito listar los resultados de ambas tablas pero que se muestre el campo tabla segun corresponda, intenté con UNION pero lo que hace es unirlos laterales, necesito que los resultados se unan por filas y no por columnas.